# strange matlab behavior

Tags: matlab

I have a deterministic matlab function. I run it on our data, and get an answer. Now if I repeat this again, running the same deterministic function on the same set of data, I get a different (incorrect answer). If I close matlab, and reopen the function, and run the function again, I will once again get the correct answer. Running the function successive times produces the wrong answer. It is not a matter of some variables not being cleared, as I can type `clearvars` in between successive runs, and the function will still produce the wrong answer until I restart matlab.

Has anyone experienced this behavior before? Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Show us the code. I suspect you're using it recursively or you're using global variables. Unless you post you code though, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I have had similar experiences, usually with running out of memory after running a script twice. Two things to consider, try using `clear all` after each run, also make sure you aren't "growing arrays". I find this is the easiest way for a variable to get values  that stick around after it should be cleared. But as Phonon said, unless we see code, we cannot really identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is directly or indirectly using a function generating random numbers, you should make sure that you use the same **state/seed** at the beginning of each run.

Example:

```
rand('twister',5489)
rand(1,5)

rand('twister',5489)
rand(1,5)
```

You will get the same output in both:

```
ans =
      0.81472      0.90579      0.12699      0.91338      0.63236
```

Note that the [random number generator syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsn94u0-1.html) has changed in recent MATLAB versions (though maintaining backward compatibility).

The new way of achieving the above is:

```
RandStream.setDefaultStream( RandStream('mt19937ar','Seed',5489) );
rand(1,5)
```

Or with the newly introduced [RNG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rng.html) function:

```
rng(5489,'twister')
rand(1,5)
```